# Corrupted docker images in Artifactory Pro

Tags: docker, artifactory

We use our on-prem Artifactory Pro ver 4.6.1 as a docker registry. Artifactory is configured to store metadata in mysql DB and binaries on the file system. Some binary content was deleted mistakenly by user ( under artifactory/data/filestore ) while trying to resolve space alerts. Among affected artifacts are a few docker images.

Now we get 500 error while pulling images from artifatory due to corrupted layer. I tried to recover artifacts from repository backups. However I get the same error while pulling recovered artifacts as well.

It looks like recovered docker images are using the same binaries as broken ones. Is this true? Any suggestions on how to recover?

Here is log error.

```
2018-06-02 16:46:53,772 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [INFO ] (o.j.r.d.v.r.h.DockerV2LocalRepoHandler:90) - Fetching docker blob 'sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4' from repo 'docker-dev-local'
2018-06-02 16:46:53,788 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:46) - Binary provider has no content for '96e379fb98bd1b401c6ee52230c11d38251572cf'
org.artifactory.storage.binstore.exceptions.BinaryNotFoundException: Binary provider has no content for '96e379fb98bd1b401c6ee52230c11d38251572cf'
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Can you find 96e379fb98bd1b401c6ee52230c11d38251572cf in your filestore (it should be inside the directory 96). Does it have the proper content (run sha1sum on it and see if it outputs the same value as the file name). I'm not sure I follow very well what happened. But it seems like you didn't manage to recover some of the files.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida   96e379fb98bd1b401c6ee52230c11d38251572cf doesn't exist under 96 directory. it was deleted on the server by mistake as i tried to explain. I get the same error for artifact that was corrupted originally and the one that was recovered from backup.

Comment: I assume that you're only backing up the database, which contains only metadata. Do you want to know how to delete all references to that file from the database?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida , thanks for your reply. i would like to know how to clean DB from references to the corrupted layer. regarding a backup - it has both filestore and metadata.  **ls** output of the directory for docker image from backup contains multiple gzip compressed data files ( docker image layers ) . sha256__a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4 is corrupted layer that causes the error and it is empty.